# Data loss in Google Analytics data in Android app

Tags: android, google-analytics

I have implemented Google Analytics in my app. I track screen name when I launch a particular page. If I launch that page for 20 times repeatedly, the screen should be tracked 20 times. But in the GA website its being reported 18 or less times. Is there any known issue reported with Google Analytics regarding loosing analytics data?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my findings,

When I send a GA hit (screen or event), this is not being dispatched to google analytics instantaneously. Instead its being stored locally and send to server in a particular interval. By default, this interval is 30 minutes, but in my app I set this interval as 2 minutes. So in every two minutes I send the GA hits, reported since last dispatch, to Google Analytics.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/dispatch

In order to protect the system from receiving more data than it can handle, Google Analytics put in place certain limits.

Here is the limit with Android SDK. For each tracker instance on a device, each app instance can send only a maximum of 60 hits in every dispatch. After one set of hits are dispatched, this quota will be replenished at a rate of 1 hit every 2 seconds.

This means, initially app can send 60 hits. After this, if we try to dispatch another set of hits after 30 seconds, we will be able to send only 15 hits.
Since we set the dispatch interval is 120 seconds, we will be able to send 60 hits in every two minutes. Even if we send only 10 hits in a previous dispatch, we will be able to send only a maximum of 60 hits in next dispatch.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/limits-quotas

**Conclusion:** So there is a chance to miss events if we send more than the allowed quota.